# Error using column alias to make operations in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having a problem with this query. I want to make an operation for my payroll system. I  Here is my query which doesn't work.

Query:

```
select
    hrrawd_timein,
    hrrawd_shiftin,
    (
      (extract(hour from (hrrawd_timein::time))
      - extract(hour from (hrrawd_shiftin::time))
      )::numeric
    ) AS shiftinhours,
    (
      (extract(minute from (hrrawd_timein::time))
      - extract(minute from (hrrawd_shiftin::time))
      )::numeric
    ) AS shiftinminutes,
    (
      ((extract(hour from (hrrawd_timein::time))
      - extract(hour from (hrrawd_shiftin::time)
      ))*60)::numeric
    )
    + 
    (
      (extract(minute from (hrrawd_timein::time))
      - extract(minute from (hrrawd_shiftin::time))
      )::numeric
    ) AS Total,
    case
      when (Total >0) then 'Late' 
      else 'EARLY'
    end as remarks
  FROM hr.hrrawd;
```

Error:

```
> ERROR:  column "total" does not exist LINE 7: case when (Total >0)
> then 'Late'
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to use [common table expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) when you need precalculated columns:

```
with cte1 as (
    select
        hrrawd_timein, hrrawd_shiftin,
        (
           extract(hour from (hrrawd_timein::time)) -
           extract(hour from (hrrawd_shiftin::time))
        )::numeric as shiftinhours,
        (
           extract(minute from (hrrawd_timein::time)) -
           extract(minute from (hrrawd_shiftin::time))
        )::numeric as shiftinminutes
    from hr.hrrawd
), cte2 as (
    select
        *,
        shiftinhours * 60 + shiftinminutes as [total]
   from cte1
)
select
    *,
    case when [total] > 0 then 'Late' else 'Early' end as remarks
from cte2
```

I think it's much cleaner than subqueries. You can also chain as many CTE as you want, and it helps you to keep [DRY principle](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself) - note how `shiftinminutes` and `shiftinhours` calculated just one time instead of two times. Readability counts, don't do the calculation twice, it will be hard to maintain in the future.

BTW, take a look at [interval data type in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html), you can extract hours and minutes from it

Comment: Thankyou sir but your code has an error "ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 7:         )::numeric) as shiftinhours,"

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
select
    *,
    case when (Total >0) then 'Late' 
     else 'EARLY' end as remarks
from (
    select  hrrawd_timein, hrrawd_shiftin,
    ((extract(hour from (hrrawd_timein::time)) - extract(hour from (hrrawd_shiftin::time)))::numeric) AS shiftinhours,
    ((extract(minute from (hrrawd_timein::time)) - extract(minute from (hrrawd_shiftin::time)))::numeric) AS shiftinminutes,
    (((extract(hour from (hrrawd_timein::time)) - extract(hour from (hrrawd_shiftin::time)))*60)::numeric)
     + 
     ((extract(minute from (hrrawd_timein::time)) - extract(minute from (hrrawd_shiftin::time)))::numeric) AS Total
    FROM hr.hrrawd) a;
```

Comment: Hello sir, It is possible instead of this (((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (hrrawd_timein::TIME)) - EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (hrrawd_shiftin::TIME)))*60)::NUMERIC)
        + ((EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (hrrawd_timein::TIME)) - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (hrrawd_shiftin::TIME)))::NUMERIC) AS Total
I'm using the ALIAS for the formula of total?
for example "(shiftinhours + shiftinminutes) as Total"
is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Standard SQL doesn't allow a column alias to be used in any other place but ORDER BY.

You need to cut&paste the calculation or better use a Derived Table:

```
SELECT
   hrrawd_timein, hrrawd_shiftin, 
   shiftinhours,
   shiftinminutes,
   Total,
   CASE WHEN (Total >0) THEN 'Late' ELSE 'EARLY' END AS remarks
FROM
 (
    SELECT  hrrawd_timein, hrrawd_shiftin, 
       ((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (hrrawd_timein::TIME)) - EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (hrrawd_shiftin::TIME)))::NUMERIC) AS shiftinhours,
       ((EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (hrrawd_timein::TIME)) - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (hrrawd_shiftin::TIME)))::NUMERIC) AS shiftinminutes,
       (((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (hrrawd_timein::TIME)) - EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (hrrawd_shiftin::TIME)))*60)::NUMERIC)
        + ((EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (hrrawd_timein::TIME)) - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (hrrawd_shiftin::TIME)))::NUMERIC) AS Total
    FROM hr.hrrawd
 ) AS dt
```

Comment: You can use alias also in `GROUP BY`, e.g.: `select t as d from generate_series(1,10,1) t group by d`

Comment: @Tomas Greif: That's why i said "Standard SQL" :-)  Some DBMSes allow it to be used in other places, too. But AFAIK only Access and Teradata allow in SELECT/WHERE.

Comment: Hello sir, It is possible instead of this (((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (hrrawd_timein::TIME)) - EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (hrrawd_shiftin::TIME)))*60)::NUMERIC)
        + ((EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (hrrawd_timein::TIME)) - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (hrrawd_shiftin::TIME)))::NUMERIC) AS Total
I'm using the ALIAS for the formula of total?
for example "(shiftinhours + shiftinminutes) as Total"
is that possible?

Comment: Yes, but then you can't use the "Total" alias in the CASE unless you nest it in another Derived Table.